# Purpose of asterisk before a CSS property

Tags: css

The following is taken from the Yahoo CSS reset. Can someone please explain the purpose of the asterisks?

```
body {
  font:13px/1.231 arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;
  *font-size:small;
  *font:x-small;
}
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

It is a browser specific CSS hack for versions 7 or below of Internet Explorer.

> *property: value
>
> Although Internet Explorer 7 corrected
>   its behavior when a property name is
>   prefixed with an underscore or a
>   hyphen, other non-alphanumeric
>   character prefixes are treated as they
>   were in IE6. Therefore, if you add a
>   non-alphanumeric character such as an
>   asterisk (*) immediately before a
>   property name, the property will be
>   applied in IE and not in other
>   browsers. Unlike with the hyphen and
>   underscore method, the CSS
>   specification makes no reservations
>   for the asterisk as a prefix, so use
>   of this hack could result in
>   unexpected behavior as the CSS
>   specifications evolve.
>
> *property: value applies the property value in IE 7 and below. It may or may
>   not work in future versions. Warning:
>   this uses invalid CSS.

From: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml

Answer (score 8):

It's an Internet Explorer hack.  If you add a non-alphanumeric character such as an asterisk (*) immediately before a property name, the property will be applied in IE7 and below, but not in other browsers.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Placing characters like that is a hack/workaround for getting IE 6 to use a style's property, while hiding it from more "sane" browsers.

From [here](http://robertmaldon.blogspot.com/2008/03/css-tricks-that-target-specific.html):

> To cut a long story short, the Internet Explorer CSS parser is overly
>   aggressive at trying to discover the names of properties and will in
>   fact ignore leading non-alphanumeric characters. From my testing this
>   appears to be the case from at least IE5 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

All browsers but IE ignore the rules.  It's known as the star hack.  I think IE7 will ignore the rules in standards mode.

In this case, the font rule is set and then overridden for IE 6 and sometimes 7.

Comment: This isn't the star-html hack. That one goes in the selector and is valid CSS.

Comment: @bobince Star Hack and Star HTML Hack are two different things: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack vs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_HTML_hack

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, asterisk prevents Firefox to read the attribute, but is valid in IE.

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS hack, that rule will only be applied to IE7 and below.

I wouldn't recommended using it though, there's better ways to fix IE incompatibilities.