# Why declare the same CSS parameter twice, but second one with a asterisk?

Tags: css, css3pie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS reset - purpose of asterik within a style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690642/css-reset-purpose-of-asterik-within-a-style)

I was reading through the CSS styles for HTML5BoilerPlate, and I came across this unfamiliar line:

```
button, input, select, textarea { 
  font-size: 100%; margin: 0; vertical-align: baseline; *vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

In particular, the second ****vertical-align***, why call twice and put an asterisk in front of it.

If anyone knows the name of the technique or why it's used, it would be a great help

Thanks!

-Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [nasty hack](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml) that can be used to target older versions of IE (other browsers ignore the invalid asterisk-prefixed value). Definitely not a good idea, far better to use IE conditional stylesheets or similar techniques.

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS hack for Internet Explorer browsers:

---

### *property: value

If you add a non-alphanumeric character such as an asterisk (*) immediately before a property name, the property will be applied in IE and not in other browsers. Unlike with the hyphen and underscore method, the CSS specification makes no reservations for the asterisk as a prefix, so use of this hack could result in unexpected behavior as the CSS specifications evolve.

*property: value applies the property value in IE 7 and below. It may or may not work in future versions. Warning: this uses invalid CSS.*

from [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

### This is a css hack and used to target `IE7 browser`.

For more reference see [**How to Target IE6, IE7, and IE8 Uniquely with 4 Characters**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/)

Answer (score 0):

It's an IE6 hack. If you put the * in front of a CSS attribute, it will only be read by IE6. Since IE6 usage is now down to 1% of the world, we can forget about this hack (unless you live in China)