# Can anyone explain the meaning of *width in a CSS class?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS reset - purpose of asterik within a style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690642/css-reset-purpose-of-asterik-within-a-style)

Can anyone explain the meaning of `*width` in a CSS class? While reading my CSS class I found:

```
 width:188px!important; *width:181px!important;
```

What is the meaning of `*width`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*width` is a browser-specific hack. It behaves as if it were `width` on Internet Explorer 7 and earlier, and has no effect on other browsers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack

Answer (score 1):

*width:181px !important; "*" is hack for targeting IE 7 Browser.

Comment: can you explain little more...????

Comment: What do you not understand about "is hack for targeting IE 7 Browser"?

Comment: See If u want to write css for only IE7 there are two ways 1 is IE conditional comments with separate css file and another one is if you want to write css for IE7 in your main css file that css should work only for IE7 that time  * hack will useful to target IE 7 Brwoser..