# CSS Asterisk (*) selector inside the brackets

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-selectors

I know that the * selector selects all elements if used as such:

Example 1:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

But what does it mean when it is put like this:

`*zoom: 1;` or `*margin-left: 2.5109110747408616%;`?

P.S: I am sorry if this question has been asked before, but I only managed to find explanation for the use of asterisk as a selector outside the brackets. (Example 1).

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS reset - purpose of asterik within a style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690642/css-reset-purpose-of-asterik-within-a-style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your old friend IE.

That's one of the many IE CSS Hacks. You can see the rest [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml).
You have to beware that it's a hack and not valid CSS. So, it could end up breaking something. If you do end up needing to use a hack, I suggest looking for alternatives first.

Comment: its better to use conditional comments, if any. IE5 + 6 are long gone now