# IE 7 fallback in CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fallback

I was playing around with this CSS in my IE9 browser:

```
className{border: red solid 1px; *border: black solid 1px;}
```

In IE 8,9 the border is shown red. 
When I turn on IE 7 compatibility mode, I see the
black border.

It looks liks the `*border` syntax is a fallback only for IE.

Does anyone know about this star (*) CSS rule & what does it do?
How well does it work for which browsers?

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690642/purpose-of-asterisk-before-a-css-property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incorrect CSS so not parsed in most (good) browsers. Older IE however parses it as valid CSS and applies the rule. Using an underscore works in the same way.

See here for [further information](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml), [or here](http://mynthon.net/howto/-/webdev/CSS-big-list-of-css-hacks.txt)

This is different to the use of the asterisk as a [universal selector in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector)

Comment: Is there somewhere an official document with information on this?

Comment: Not sure about official documentation, I've never been able to find anything from MS

Answer (score 0):

```
*+html SELECTOR {}
```

targets only IE7 and keeps the CSS valid. This should be prefered.

Comment: Conditional stylesheets are better than hacky css ;-)

Comment: depends on the situation... conditional comments always result in extra files. This means you have an extra request to the server. If you have one single condition in your css that needs a fallback, I would always go for *+html. If you have a lot of stuff then yes, use the extra file :)

Answer (score 0):

The only time I ever use the star is for the inline block fix for ie7, the star just allows you to target ie6 (from i remember) as well as ie7. You can also use an exclamation mark to target ie7 if you're feeling lazy (!border:1px solid #000)