# Horizontal scrolling div without fixed height with all contained divs the height of the tallest child

Tags: html, css

JSFiddle: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fLYCb/)

I'm looking for a way to have a container div with a height equal to its tallest child.

Every other child should be sized to the height of the container.

I also need the container to scroll horizontally if the children would exceed its width.

So far I have tried using inline-block and float: left but have not gotten the results I want. Setting height: 100% on the children also doesn't have the desired effect. Using overflow: auto on the container still wrapped the last element onto the next line.

I'm pretty confident that I could accomplish this with JavaScript by grabbing the height of the tallest child and resizing appropriately and setting a fixed height on the container. I'd prefer to not use JavaScript though and I think this might be possible just with CSS trickery.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li></ul></div>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li></ul></div>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></div>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></div>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></div>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></div>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></div>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul></div>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></div>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></div>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></div>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></div>
    <div class='boxed'><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.boxed { display: inline-block; border: 1px solid black; }

.container { overflow-x: auto; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first issue, you could make the elements `display:table-cell` as opposed to `inline-block`. This will cause them to take the height of the tallest sibling element. I'd also suggest adding `vertical-align:bottom` to the elements in order to align them to the bottom of the parent element. If that's not the behavior you were going for, there is `middle`, and `top` too.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LD8cj/)

```
.boxed {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

For the second issue, just add `white-space:nowrap` to the parent element to prevent the children elements from wrapping. A horizontal scrollbar will be created when the children elements exceed the width of the parent elements.

```
.container {
    border:1px solid red;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: With vertical-align: top that looks perfect on my actual page. Thanks. One caveat is that MDN lists table-cell as not working with IE7 (which is the oldest browser I support). Do you have a possibility for making it not-ugly with IE7, even if not perfect?

Comment: @CLandry Unfortunately I don't have any ideas on how to support IE7 in this case. [This approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690642/purpose-of-asterisk-before-a-css-property) came to mind, however I don't know of any properties than would behave as `table-cell` does. It's a shame browsers like these have to be supported :)

Comment: Thanks again. I'm going to convert it to a table, since table-cell fakes a td, I'll just turn it into an actual one. It's ugly, but should work across all my target browsers.