# Clearfix for IE 6/7?

Tags: css, css-float

I am using the [micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) on a website I am developing. It works fine but I have one question about it; that I was hoping someone could clear up for me.

On the above webpage, the clearfix hack contains:

```
/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Obviously just adding that to my css triggers a warning because of the `*`. How exactly do I include the above rule to trigger hasLayout? Do I simply remove the `*`? Or is there a way to include an `if IE 6/7` within a stylesheet itself?

I wasn't exactly clear on if I should remove the `*` or just paste the code as is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690642/purpose-of-asterisk-before-a-css-property

Comment: It's a hack. It'll simply not validate because it isn't valid CSS by definition. You'll have to load a separate file or live with that.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will just add it to my IE 6/7 stylesheet rather than living with the warning.

Comment: @NickManning the question is over 5 months old, during the good ole ie7 days for your local library...

Comment: 5 months ago is like 2 months ago!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is there a way to include an if IE 6/7 within a stylesheet itself?

Use the IE6/7 media query:

```
 @media, { .cf { zoom: 1 } }
```

**References**

- [Sitepoint CSS Reference: @media](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/at-media)

Comment: this is not valid css

Comment: @Alex Exactly. It only works in IE6/7, and that's why it is the accepted answer.