# CSS file is working in Chrome but nor in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a SAP Portal Custom Component which contains a JSP file (with my javascript Code). This component is on a SAP Portal page with a further iView. This further iView (contains the iframe) contains multiple headers (,,) and text. My goal is to create a table of contents () dynamically using the javascript and style it with the CSS file shown below and add it to the iframe. The Javascript runs great in every browser and creates my table of contents. The styling only works in Chrome though. If I open my page in IE the CSS is not applied.

```
#contentsdiv{
border: 1px solid #CCC;
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
padding: 5px 5px;
}


#contentstitle{
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
padding: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
}

#expandButton{
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
font-size:14px;
padding: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#expandButton:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

#listdiv > ul{
padding-left:0px;
list-style-type: none;
padding-bottom:2px;
}

#listdiv > ul > li > ul, #listdiv > ul > li > ul >li >ul{ 
list-style-type: none;
padding-bottom:2px;
}

#listdiv > ul > li > a{
text-decoration:none;
font-size:14px;
}

#listdiv > ul > li > ul > li > a{
text-decoration:none;
font-size:14px;
}

#listdiv > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a{
text-decoration:none;
font-size:14px;
}

#listdiv > ul > li > a:hover , #listdiv > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover , #listdiv > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's not working exactly? None of the styles are being applied or the file isn't loading? Add the HTML and more details, please.

Comment: Need a lot more information about this iframe and what is or isn't working. Best guess is it has nothing to do with the actual rules themselves. Check your browser console to see what gets loaded

Answer (score 1):

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>My Web Page</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>Content goes here.</p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

frame your html with this meta tag included and remove all the * symbols. it is not supported by IE

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the * in front of your attributes.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it's actually a hack for IE7 and below, that is supposed to be ignored by other browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1690683/1913729

Answer (score -1):

CSS hacks and were often used to address issues in older versions of Internet Explorer (IE7 and below). However, modern browsers and IE8+ have better standards support, and these hacks are generally not needed * add before style.

```
*zoom: 1; *display: inline;
```

Some browsers have default styles that might affect your layout. Use a CSS reset to normalize styles across different browsers.

```
/* CSS Reset */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This question is a decade old... was this addition really necessary?

Comment: No, no it was not